# How to apply bitcoin address generated offonlie to online?

Tags: php, bitcoin

I'm really new to Bitcoin. Now I can generate bitcoin address by Javascript (ref:http://procbits.com/2013/08/27/generating-a-bitcoin-address-with-javascript). My question is: the address generated by JS is offline I think. How does Bitcoin know this address can be used online? Any code would be used (PHP preferred)?

Comment: Author of the article that you linked to here. When you say "online", I think what you mean, is that when it's in the blockchain. The only time this happens is when an address has Bitcoins associated with it. i.e. You can generate a Bitcoin private key and address "offline"  (not connected to the internet) and tell someone the address. You can then receive coins at this address. The private key is then used to prove ownership or to spend the coins. Hopefully this clears it up a bit.

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the private keys into your bitcoin client, else the client will not be able to check the address because it doesn't own the private key.

Pretty easy with PHP, but I would not recommend it, since it can take a bit of time to import an private key.

```
$bitcoin->importprivkey("<privatekey>");
```

or if you want it to have an label in the client you can do

```
$bitcoin->importprivkey("<privatekey>", "<label>");
```